# Full-text search only first 100 characters of column values

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How can I perform a full-text search in MySQL that only searches through the first 100 characters of the values in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a prefix length when you create the full text index

```
ALTER TABLE  table_name ADD FULLTEXT (
    column (100)
);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

> Prefix lengths are given in characters for nonbinary string types and in bytes for binary string types. That is, index entries consist of the first length characters of each column value for CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns, and the first length bytes of each column value for BINARY, VARBINARY, and BLOB columns.